# Move Magnifier window

Tags: c#

I want to use my Android phone to control the magnifier on Windows 7. I can call it by simulating the shortcut key "WIN" + "+". Then, I got the magnifier on the screen. When I tried to move the magnifier window, it usually could be done by moving the mouse pointer. The problem is when I use `SetCursorPos` from win32 as following to move mouse pointer

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
```

only the mouse pointer moved, the magnifier did not follow the pointer at all.

What would you suggest, in C# please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnifier tracks mouse activity, not cursor activity. Use `SendInput` to simulate mouse activity.